# Why can't variables of different type be named the same?

Tags: c#

I know the below is illegal in the same code block in C# but is there any possible way around it apart from the obvious (naming them differently) ?

```
    string test;
    int test;
```

Comment: why downvote? It's a perfectly reasonable question!

Comment: What would you do with `Console.WriteLine("{0}", test);` ?

Comment: @Phil: No, it's not only not reasonable, it's just ***pointless***

Comment: and yet again I wish you could see the downvoters and vote them down a bit - this is valid and indeed better than most "please write my program" questions

Comment: @Phil - this is very basic question if you read the docs carefully you find it easily

Comment: @Armen Whether it is pointless or not is clearly subjective. This question holds value since it teaches any reader the importance of using correct naming for readability's sake. Just because YOU think it's pointless doesn't mean there's no value in posing the question!

Comment: cheers Phil/Carsten - I would also like to who down votes.

Comment: @Pranay - A great deal of questions asked on SO are very basic and can be found without even reading the docs carefully.

Comment: even worse - most questions here could be answered by simply googling them (and in most cases you will see a link to this site first ;) ) - I find this one rather refreshing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Ambiguity

Ok, let's assume that is valid and you can do

```
string test = "Hallo";
int test = 1;
```

should

```
test.ToString();
```

result in `"Hallo`" or in `"1"`?

It would just not be possible for the compiler to know what object you are refering to in some circumstances as you can see. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I see 7 answers and only this explains the why.